# Automating report layout with data driven pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, data-driven-pages

Pretend that I have a geodatabase or shapefile with many layers of roads, waterways, gas-line network, etc. People come to my office to give me coordinates of their land property and ask if it intersects with any of the data features found in the general database or not.

**How to make a (map on-demand tool) to get the sample output in the
picture attached, using ArcGIS 10.x?**

*NOTE:*

> Intersection with every feature might be in a separate page (but all
>   have the same layout ... kind of map book)

Sample output is here
[image: Sample Report Output]

Comment: welcome to GIS SE! you mention data driven pages in the title. It seems like that is part of your solution. What have you tried so far? Right now the question is a bit too vague and broad. You need to focus it, or it might be closed.

Comment: Data-driven pages is just an idea came to my mind as I was posting my question. I hope the picture explains more

Comment: This is what some call a maps on demand application.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - create a table with all the fields you want on your layout - if you don't need to store history, you can just keep one record with the most recent values in it.  Make sure your table has an ID field, and put "1" in as the ID

Step 2 - do an intersect (ArcToolbox, Analysis Tools, Overlay, Intersect) to determine where the conflicts lie.  You probably want an output type of point.  This creates an output layer you can use to control your data driven pages

Step 3 - add an ID field to the output from step 2 - calculate the field to be 1 for all rows so the join below works.

Step 4 - do a join between the table from step 1 and the output from step 2... this makes all your table fields available to add to the layout.

Step 5 - set up data driven pages using your intersect output(has it's own toolbar which you may need to add)

Step 6 - use the Insert -> Dynamic Text ->  Data Driven Page Attribute menu item to add all your fields to your layout.

Step 7 - export to PDF or print, make sure you select all pages.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Can some of these steps be automated in something like a model to be used repeatedly by a non-professional employee?

Comment: I'm very familiar with Python coding but I almost never touch Model Builder... so I'm not really sure what you can do with it.